# The following code in Java and Android results to differ

Tags: java, android, calendar

The following code produces different results when I run it in Java as opposed to when I run it on Android:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();//

for(int k = 1; k < 10; k++) {
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2013);
    cal.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, k);
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 1);
    System.out.println(sdf.format(cal.getTime()));
}
```

The result on Java (JDK 1.6):

[image: java]

The result on Android (Emulator with Android 4.2.2):
[image]

Why is this the case? How can I fix this?

Comment: could you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: what u are telling is if u run in java your getting different result and in android different result....

Comment: please add the two different results to your question

Comment: wat u r trying is absurd.first u r setting the week(1st,2nd ,3rd) of 2013,then u are setting that week to have first day of the week(sunday) how it could be possible every time ..lol

Comment: @ShakeebShaheen doesn't seem absurd to me. -a rational way to achieve the start dates of every week in the year.

Answer (score 1):

Following the rules in the Android developers documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html) it seems it should work by virtue of the last rule (and the fact that these have been set most recently).

> Inconsistent information. If fields conflict, the calendar will give
>   preference to fields set more recently. For example, when determining
>   the day, the calendar will look for one of the following combinations
>   of fields. The most recent combination, as determined by the most
>   recently set single field, will be used.
>
> ```
>  MONTH + DAY_OF_MONTH
>  MONTH + WEEK_OF_MONTH + DAY_OF_WEEK
>  MONTH + DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH + DAY_OF_WEEK
>  DAY_OF_YEAR
>  DAY_OF_WEEK + WEEK_OF_YEAR
> ```

A possible bug in the Android implementation?
I would try setting the DAY Of Week first and then the month that might work around the issue. Alternately iterate forward using add or roll seven days at a time from the first week start as an option.

Comment: well if this is a bug we should report it... can anyone else confirm this?